# Splitting a string by whitespace in SBCL

Tags: split, common-lisp, sbcl

I've been trying to split a simple whitespace-delimited string into individual parts, for example:

I have:

```
"test   123    test2            test3"
```

and the function is to return:

```
('test' '123' 'test2' 'test3')
```

My lisp distribution is sbcl, and I was experimenting with split-sequence module. It works well, yet I can not seem to input something in the lines of "\s+" as the delimiter.

Before I write my own function for this, I saw that split command also exists, where splitting is as simple as:

```
* (split "\\s+" "foo   bar baz
frob")
("foo" "bar" "baz" "frob")
```

Unfortunately split doesn't work in SBCL, as far as I know. Thanks for any suggestion on how can this be imported/ done in SBCL.

Comment: You can use the [cl-ppcre](http://weitz.de/cl-ppcre/) library.

Comment: Thank you, I will try with this approach. As I am building a command line tool, I hope this won't contribute too much to final binary size..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CL-USER> (split-sequence:split-sequence-if
            (lambda (item)
              (position item " -+"))
            "aa bb  ccc  dddd--eee++++ffff"
            :remove-empty-subseqs t)

("aa" "bb" "ccc" "dddd" "eee" "ffff")
29
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a pull request coming (**edit**: it's merged) in the little [cl-str](https://github.com/vindarel/cl-str) library to do that with:

```
(str:words " aa   bb   ") ;; => ("aa", "bb")
```

In the meanwhile, we have `split` and `trim`.

`cl-str` is meant to be a modern and consistent string manipulation library that eases some stuff (otherwise not straigthforward and requiring too many libraries) like trim, concat, join, split, replace, blank?,…

Comment: Thanks, I managed to solve this using split library at the end.